# Android studio Error after update from 2.1 to 2.3 (Can't startup)

Tags: java, android, bash, android-studio, intellij-idea

I've downloaded the latest android studio update (2.3) as a .zip file in order to update the one I have.

Now, my problem is that I cannot open android studio anymore when updating it from version 2.1 to 2.3 (using the terminal ). 
My Operating System is:

- Ubuntu (14.04 LTS)
- JDK Version is 9 (latest one)
- java version "9-ea".
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+140)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-ea+140, mixed mode)

and as for java home: 
 `$JAVA_HOME -> bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle: Is a directory`

When I write `cd /opt/android-studio/bin` and then `./studio.sh`  on my terminal I get this error:

```
Looking in classpath from com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader@6d5380c2 for /com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Found library resource at jar:file:/opt/android-studio/lib/jna.jar!/com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Trying /home/karim/.AndroidStudioPreview2.3/system/tmp/jna2261948218159416677.tmp
Found jnidispatch at /home/karim/.AndroidStudioPreview2.3/system/tmp/jna2261948218159416677.tmp
[   5549]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator' 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:203)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:47)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:358)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:248)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:536)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$8(ApplicationImpl.java:429)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:494)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:443)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:436)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:103)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:384)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:196)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FN_AAPT2
    at com.android.sdklib.BuildToolInfo.<init>(BuildToolInfo.java:352)
    at com.android.sdklib.BuildToolInfo.fromStandardDirectoryLayout(BuildToolInfo.java:224)
    at com.android.sdklib.BuildToolInfo.fromLocalPackage(BuildToolInfo.java:238)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.getLatestBuildTool(AndroidSdkHandler.java:772)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.PlatformTarget.<init>(PlatformTarget.java:144)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.AndroidTargetManager.getTargetMap(AndroidTargetManager.java:94)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.AndroidTargetManager.getTargets(AndroidTargetManager.java:80)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.AndroidTargetManager.getTargetFromHashString(AndroidTargetManager.java:154)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.findTargetByHashString(AndroidSdkData.java:216)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkAdditionalData.getBuildTarget(AndroidSdkAdditionalData.java:126)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidPlatform.parse(AndroidPlatform.java:90)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkAdditionalData.getAndroidPlatform(AndroidSdkAdditionalData.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidPlatform.getInstance(AndroidPlatform.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.getEligibleAndroidSdks(IdeSdks.java:518)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.getFirstAndroidSdk(IdeSdks.java:170)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.getAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.GradleSpecificInitializer.setupSdks(GradleSpecificInitializer.java:278)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.GradleSpecificInitializer.run(GradleSpecificInitializer.java:115)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.activateAndroidStudioInitializerExtensions(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:198)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.<init>(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:495)
    ... 28 more
[   5557]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 2.3 Beta 1  Build #AI-162.3573574 
[   5557]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 1.8.0_112-release 
[   5557]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
[   5557]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
[   5558]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Linux 

Start Failed: Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:203)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:47)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:358)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:248)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:536)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$8(ApplicationImpl.java:429)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:494)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:443)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:436)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:103)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:384)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:196)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FN_AAPT2
    at com.android.sdklib.BuildToolInfo.<init>(BuildToolInfo.java:352)
    at com.android.sdklib.BuildToolInfo.fromStandardDirectoryLayout(BuildToolInfo.java:224)
    at com.android.sdklib.BuildToolInfo.fromLocalPackage(BuildToolInfo.java:238)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.getLatestBuildTool(AndroidSdkHandler.java:772)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.PlatformTarget.<init>(PlatformTarget.java:144)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.AndroidTargetManager.getTargetMap(AndroidTargetManager.java:94)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.AndroidTargetManager.getTargets(AndroidTargetManager.java:80)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.AndroidTargetManager.getTargetFromHashString(AndroidTargetManager.java:154)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.findTargetByHashString(AndroidSdkData.java:216)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkAdditionalData.getBuildTarget(AndroidSdkAdditionalData.java:126)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidPlatform.parse(AndroidPlatform.java:90)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkAdditionalData.getAndroidPlatform(AndroidSdkAdditionalData.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidPlatform.getInstance(AndroidPlatform.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.getEligibleAndroidSdks(IdeSdks.java:518)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.getFirstAndroidSdk(IdeSdks.java:170)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.getAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.GradleSpecificInitializer.setupSdks(GradleSpecificInitializer.java:278)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.GradleSpecificInitializer.run(GradleSpecificInitializer.java:115)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.activateAndroidStudioInitializerExtensions(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:198)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.<init>(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run
```

Comment: Restore a backup or ask your sysadmin or ask at [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour).

Answer (score 4):

I got an error like this one when multiple versions of Android tools were installed on top of one another.

Try removing `tools/lib/common.jar` from your `ANDROID_HOME` folder.